# Configure and connect to OpenVPN Client GUI in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gui, openvpn

Connect to through CLI

```
sudo openvpn --config /path/to/openvpn.ovpn
```

But, how to configure and connect to OpenVPN through GUI.

I installed `network-manager-openvpn-gnome` with using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

Answer (score 7):

Try installing just `network-manager-openvpn`:

```
sudo apt install network-manager-openvpn
```

also make sure `openvpn` is installed:

```
sudo apt install openvpn
```

Comment: it does not add anything to VPN Connection menu item. It is still disabled

Comment: Did you already run `sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome` and reboot?

Comment: yes. I did exactly that.. ubuntu 16.04, last updates. but I see there is a way to add OpenvVPN in edit connection section. It is just there is disabled "add vpn connection"in VPN Connection section of the menu